# Make Hibernate inline one String parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a custom ORDER BY in my SQL using criteria builder, and I have the following code:

```
cb.desc(
  cb.selectCase()
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Monday"), cb.literal(1))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Tuesday"), cb.literal(2))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Wednesday"), cb.literal(3))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Thursday"), cb.literal(4))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Friday"), cb.literal(5))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Saturday"), cb.literal(6))
        .when(cb.equal(root.get("eventTimeGroup"), "Sunday"), cb.literal(7))
    .otherwise(cb.literal(8)));
```

As you may know, Hibernate would make "Monday", "Tuesday", ... parameters, which results in the final query showing a question mark for each of those Strings. The DB I am trying to query is Druid and seems it has a problem reading the parameters in the ORDER BY CASE WHEN THEN clause, and therefore I am wondering **if it is possible to ask Hibernate to do inline query instead of parameter binding ONLY for the Strings in this ORDER BY CASE WHEN THEN clause** (I know the hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode property but that is a global setting I believe)?

Thank you!